# PyTest with Flask-Security - issue logging in for testing

Tags: python, testing, flask, pytest, flask-security

I have a working flask app and I'm adding testing using the **pytest** library.

99% of the app's functionality requires users to login, and I'm using flask-security to manage this.

The app works well, however, I am struggling to add testing - specifically, to login a test user, then test views decorated with the 'login_required' decorator from the underlying flask-login package.  I have read many tutorials and stackoverflow questions, but haven't been able to 'fix' this...

I understand about working within the application context, but I believe that the conftest.py is set up correctly for this.

Code below.  Can anyone suggest what i might be doing wrong?  Thanks a million, in advance.

application.py

```
def create_app(config_class=DevConfig):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    ##  add extensions

    from user.models import User, Role
    from user.forms import ExtendedRegisterForm, ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security.init_app(app, user_datastore, register_form=ExtendedRegisterForm,
        confirm_register_form=ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm)

    ## register blueprints

    return app
```

tests/conftest.py

```
import pytest
import os

from application import create_app, security
from application import db as _db

from config import TestConfig
from user.models import User, Role
from .utils import valid_user, create_roles_users


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def test_client():
    app = create_app(config_class=TestConfig)

    testing_client = app.test_client()

    # application context
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    yield testing_client

    ctx.pop()


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def init_db():
    _db.create_all()

    create_roles_users(security, _db)

    yield _db

    _db.drop_all()
```

tests/utils.py

```
valid_user = {
    "first_name": "Test", 
    "last_name": "User",
    "email": "test_user@test.com", 
    "password": "test_pwd"
    }

def login(client, username=valid_user['email'], password=valid_user['password']):
    return client.post('/user/login', data=dict(
        email=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)


def logout(client):
    return client.get('/user/logout', follow_redirects=True)


def create_roles_users(security, db):
    # create roles
    roles = ['submitter', 'approver', 'admin', 'db-admin', 'leave-tracker']
    for role in roles:
        security.datastore.find_or_create_role(name=role)

    # create and activate users
    users = []
    users.append(valid_user)
    created_users = []

    for user_args in users:
        created_user = security.datastore.create_user(**user_args)
        security.datastore.activate_user(created_user)

        created_users.append(created_user)

    # assign submitter role to users
    for user in created_users:
        for role in roles:
            r = security.datastore.find_or_create_role(role)
            security.datastore.add_role_to_user(user, r)

    db.session.commit()
```

test view after login

```
from tests.utils import login, logout, valid_user


def test_homepage_not_loggedin(test_client):
    """
    GIVEN no authenticated user
    WHEN the '/' page is requested (GET)
    THEN check the user is forwarded to log in
    """
    rv = test_client.get('/')
    assert rv.status_code == 302

    rv = test_client.get('/', follow_redirects=True)
    assert b'Please log in' in rv.data


def test_homepage_loggedin(test_client, init_db):
    """
    GIVEN logged in user
    WHEN the '/timesheets' page is requested (GET)
    THEN check the user is not requested to log in
    """

    with test_client:

        rv = login(test_client)
        assert rv.status_code == 200

        rv = test_client.get('/timesheets', follow_redirects=True)
        assert b'Please log in' not in rv.data
```

After running pytest, I get a 'pass' on the first test (not_loggedin) and a 'fail' on the second test (loggedin) - the text returned shows that the user is still forwarded to the /user/login page.

In the config I have switched `LOGIN_DISABLED = False` to `LOGIN_DISABLED = True`, and it gets around the fail, however, this results in an `AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'id'`, since the user is not logged in and therefore anonymous.

Comment: A couple possibilities - but first - remember that with forms you always get a 200 response - whether you actually logged in successfully or not. You might be having an issue with CSRF or something else - so look at 'rv' response in a debugger from your login(xxx) request. a successful login SHOULD have redirected you - so you can check that as well. Also - this: https://github.com/jwag956/flask-security/tree/master/examples/fsqlalchemy1/tests might be helpful - one way to mock out Flask-Security altogether...

Answer (score 0):

The hint from jwag led to the answer, for anyone finding this question.  By setting `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED` to False in the config, this allows successful login.  Kudos to jwag.